# What to do if I don't agree with an edit to my question?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507403/ok-to-call-deleteobject-on-objects-own-managedobjectcontext) was edited by a user for no reason.
Check the edits he did -> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34507403/revisions.
I have rolled back the edit, but is there any guide where I can know what I did was right?

Comment: No guide will tell you whether or not your own edit expresses better what you have in mind.

Comment: You probably just @ping him and tell what's wrong. I.e. bolding the variable wasn't appropriate (I agree), excess "thanks" (I agree), no need to change the variable name (there I won't agree probably, what's wrong with providing a more meaningful variable name, it's not the code golf) and title (I don't agree, the title edit was fine).

Comment: @PatrickHofman My bad. I read it incorrectly. I thought the editor actually removed that last line while they added it. The title change was a good edit though.

Comment: Indeed. I reapplied that one @Eran.

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to rollback an edit if you disagree with it. And in this case, making code blocks bold is a bad practice, so I agree you rolled it back. Also, adding fluff like 'Thanks in advance' is an even worse practice.

There isn't a set guideline when to rollback an edit. That is because it is very hard to determine what is right and wrong. You as a post owner, have some authority over your post. Additionally, if an edit makes your post better, you should keep it. But what exactly makes it better and what not? That is very opinionated, and therefore hard to write down in a set of rules.

If a user keeps editing, don't keep rolling back. Just flag the post for a moderator to check it.

Comment: And in my opinion we should not fear posting [such comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507403/is-it-ok-to-call-deleteobject-on-objects-own-managedobjectcontext#comment56756606_34507403), with chance of teaching the editor it was a bad idea